# Elasticsearch universal search query

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a string "Jhon Abraham 18". I want to create search query that will search by divided by spaces words from the string in an index. This search have to be set to all fields of the index and you don't know what meaning have to be mapped(set) to a field.
So, I have a document:

```
{
  "_index": "recipient",
  "_type": "recipient",
  "_id": "37a15258d9",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "name": "Jhon ",
    "surname": "Abraham",
    "age": "18 ",
}
```

and I don't know to what fields of index meanings Jhon, Abraham and 18 correspond. I just have a string and by this string I want to search in all fields of the index documents. I can divide it by separete words by spaces but I don't know exact mapping fields for search. Also, I want to do it at Java.
I'll be appreciate for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use query_string in elasticsearch.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

This will solve your problem.

Comment: but I don't know exact field to what I have to map meaning from the string

Comment: You don't need to. By default query_string search in all fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi match query, writing all fields or wildcards.

[Multi Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html)

Comment: Did it like you said, but still have one more issue.
Fully discribed it here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/universal-search/162159/10